# Is there any reason to have an SSL certificate on a forward-only domain?

Tags: ssl, domain, forwarding

Our company acquired a new domain name a few years ago and have been forwarding (a significant amount of) traffic from our old domain, which no longer hosts content. Is there any reason to continue paying for an SSL certificate installed at the old domain?

Comment: Totally, but the vague nature of that other question prevented me from finding it. I suggest editing its title!

Comment: Good idea. I've changed the title of this other question.

Answer (score 0):

Your old domain require valid SSL certificate, if you want to redirect HTTPS traffic from your old domain to your new domain. Otherwise people trying to access your old site with HTTPS are likely to get warning on the browser and they won't be redirected to proper destination (New domain).